# Putting bracket around word with regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I want to add brackets around an expression which can contain letters or dots in a sentence.

I have tried this function :

```
def add_brackets(sentence, word):
    s = r'(\b' + word + r'\b)' 
    c  = re.compile(s, re.I)
    return(c.sub(r'[\1]', sentence))
```

With

```
sentence = 'Le pressostat h.p. est installé'
word = 'est installé'
```

The output is good :

```
'Le pressostat h.p. [est installé]'
```

However with :

```
sentence = 'Le pressostat h.p. est installé'
word = 'pressostat h.p.'
```

The output is without brackets :

```
'Le pressostat h.p. est installé'
```

But with

```
sentence = 'Le pressostat h.p. est installé'
word = 'pressostat h.p' #no final dot
```

The output is with brackets :

```
'Le [pressostat h.p]. est installé'
```

The problem may be the final '.' because without it the function works. How may I include the dot in the regex expression ?

Comment: `s = fr'(?<!\w){re.escape(word)}(?!\w)'`

Comment: try `('['+word+']').join(sentence.split(word))`